# Condition not resolving correctly

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools

I have this condition in Javascript:

`const isObject = (typeof item.data.data[field] == "object" || typeof masterRecord.data.data[field] == "object") && item.data.data[field] != null;`

If I use Chrome devTools to step through the code, isObject resolves as *true*, but this is not correct.

If I insert a breakpoint at the specific line and break down the conditions into its parts, I get the following values:

- `typeof item.data.data[field] == "object"` -> false
- `typeof masterRecord.data.data[field] == "object"` -> false
- `(typeof item.data.data[field] == "object" || typeof masterRecord.data.data[field] == "object")` -> false
- `item.data.data[field] != null` -> true

...and finally, the condition as a whole, with its correct output:

- `(typeof item.data.data[field] == "object" || typeof masterRecord.data.data[field] == "object") && item.data.data[field] != null` -> false

Ideas?

Comment: There are only 2 possibilities. 1) There is a race condition and stopping in the debugger is masking that from you 2) You've made a mistake in your analysis of the individual parts. In either case, to give you an actual answer we would need a [mcve] demonstrating the problem.

Comment: I've checked and cannot reproduce the issue. Thank you for the help
(I've moved on as the issue is no longer relevant)